# "In addition to" vs "In addition of"

Tags: prepositions

I stumbled upon the sentence:

> This book is dedicated to my mother, who has taken care of her family throughout her life without  the slightest negligence, in addition to being sincere towards her duties as a school teacher, [...]"

I was wondering about the "in addition to". Grammatically, the preposition "in addition to" is correct, but for me, as a non native english speaker, it reads strange.
Probably because of the following "being".

Wouldn't one rather use a "besides" or "in addition of" instead, or is an "in addition of" generally wrong?

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I've never heard *in addition of*, nor do I know whether it's wrong, so I don't think, from personal experience, that *in addition of* is used...

Comment: well, when you google for wikipedia articles that use "in addition of" you'll find quite a few. Also in the context of "in addition of being". That made me pensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"In addition of" is totally wrong. The preposition (when present) is always "to".

However, there are at least two situations where "of" appears next and it is not a mistake.

1. When the phrase "in addition" has completed, and the sentence continues with yet another phrase.

> *In addition*, of all the weather satellites in orbit, only DMSP can "see" at night.

2. When referring to mathematical addition.

> Instruction and practice in *addition of fractions*